# Detect if iPhone is awake or in sleep mode from app running in the background

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible for an app running in the background to detect if the iPhone is awake, i.e not in sleep mode?

Comment: I don't believe so - for what purpose?

Comment: It was something we started to discuss at work today. I don't have a specific use case. Could be something like having an app running in the background and playing a sound while the phone is in use, but stop it when the app enters sleep mode.